# Cell at indexpath 0 not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with sections inside of them. All works great, but I can't seem to figure out how to customize the very fist index path. For example, I know this is very easily achievable through a normal tableview like so:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell)
    {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
         if (indexPath.row == 0) 
         {      
             cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"My Custom text";
             NSLog(@"%@",pm1.customText1); 
         }
    }
}
```

I have tried the above implementation and it does not seem to work for me. Is there a different approach for section headers to achieve the same result with a normal tableview? Do I need to inject a "fake" section in my dictionary?

Comment: Why do you dequeue, then re-alloc a cell ? You should do one of the two, but not both.

Comment: Why are you calling dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier and then always creating a new one?

Comment: Please see revision. Forgot to add the appropriate logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
          cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"My Custom text";

            NSLog(@"%@",pm1.customText1);

        }
return cell;
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it now the first cell is customize only when cell is nil.

You should move it out of the if statement.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //check for first cell
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"My first Cell";
        NSLog(@"%@",pm1.customText1);
    }else{
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Other cells";
        NSLog(@"other cells");
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Does not change. That works fine for a normal tableview. But not for sections.

Comment: You did not mention section please elaborate

Comment: @wayon what do you mean it does not work for sections, my code will display `My first Cell` on each first cell of each section, what did you want exactly